# perlcritic with additional profiles

Tags: perl, perl-critic

Is it possible to "add" another profile to perlcritic default profile, or run perlcritic with multiple profiles? I do not want to skip/replace the default profile. I need to add an additional profile to it.

[I know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51499/are-there-any-good-automated-frameworks-for-applying-coding-standards-in-perl) I could export current profile and append my additions, then use that as the default profile. But in that case I should make sure I'll do the same thing after each perlcritic update since the default profile might have been updated.

Comment: Can you clarify your meaning a bit?  Are you saying that you have an existing `.perlcriticrc` file that the team/project uses (i.e. your "default") and you would like to override that with an additional (say, user-specific) profile?

Answer (score 0):

Your `.perlcriticrc` modifies the default profile, rather than replacing it. There's the `--only` command-line option, to tell it to only use the policies listed in your `.perlcriticrc`, and skip the default profile. You can also specify this within your `.perlcriticrc`, by putting `only = 1` above the first named section of the file. If you don't specify `--only` on the command line, or `only = 1` in your `.perltidyrc`, your `.perltidyrc` will modify the default profile, rather than throw it out and replace it.

See the [perlcritic POD](http://search.cpan.org/~thaljef/Perl-Critic-1.118/bin/perlcritic) for more details.